# GKTurnBasedMatch ignores playerAttributes

Tags: ios, game-center

When I create the following GKRequest object to create a turn based game:

```
GKMatchRequest *gameRequest = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
gameRequest.minPlayers = 2;
gameRequest.maxPlayers = 2;
gameRequest.playerAttributes = MY_ROLE_1;
```

This request should not be matched with another request with the same playerAttributes, but it is. Does anyone know if playerAttributes are ignored for turn based games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW6

> Your game defines a complete set of roles; all roles defined by your game must be filled by the time the match is created. This means there is a careful coordination between the roles that you define and the number of players allowed in the match. Thus, player attributes require additional design and testing effort.

Turn based games can be created with empty seats and players are found when it is their turn. If the above statement is true, then playerAttributes are ignored for turn based games because they can't all be filled by the time the match is created otherwise.

Comment: I don’t understand this, in that it seems to be ignored for me as well.

In my game, both players are creating a GKMatchRequest with the same playerAttributes, but get matched to each other. (I am also setting playerGroup, but that seems to work the way I expect.) This seems incorrect. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We are clearly into documentation hermeneutics here, but I cannot help but wonder that Apple [elsewhere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW12) refers to Chess (clearly a turn-based game, one would think) in relation to `playerAttributes`. Having said that, my app uses `GKTurnBasedMatch` and (for now) also sees its `playerAttributes` (but not `playerGroup`) ignored.